# How to remove List of Figures page generated by package figcaps

Tags: tables, floats

I am using the figcaps package to place my Figures and tables at the end of the document. However, I do not want the List of Figures page that appears with figure captions before the actual figures. How can I suppress this page?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[figon,print figures]{figcaps}

\def\tablepagename{TABLES}
\def\figurepagename{FIGURES}

\begin{document}
.....
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the internal `\@figurecaps`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[figon,print figures]{figcaps}

\def\tablepagename{TABLES}
\def\figurepagename{FIGURES}

\makeatletter
\def\@figurecaps{\@ifundefined{tf@pof}{}{\if@filesw
  \immediate\closeout\tf@pof\fi
  \@ifundefined{appendixname}{}{\def\appendixname{}}
  \parindent\z@
  \reset@figtab%\clearpage\section*{\figurecapname}\vspace{1cm}%
    %\@mkboth{\uppercase{\figurecapname}}{\uppercase{\figurecapname}}%
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\figurecapname}%
  %\def\figure{\def\addcontentsline####1####2####3{}%
    %\def\@captype{figure}%
    %\begingroup\set@literal\@fcaponly
   %}\def\endfigure{\endgroup\bigskip}%
  %{\let\@makecaption=\@makefcaption
  %\@input{\jobname.\lof}%
  %}%
  \clearpage}}%
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

test text 
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does get rid of the Figure Captions page, but also seems to leave a blank page in between the Tables and Figures page, which I don't want.

Comment: @Maria as you see in the image in my answer, this is not the general case, so please edit your question and add there a little, yet *complete* document (like the one in my answer) allowing us to reproduce the undesired bahaviour.